# Page Controller changes but Carousel does not SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui, carousel

I have this code to change the Carousel index when tapped on the button. When I tap the button only the page indicator dot is changing but the Carousel stays the same. But when I scroll carousel page indicator changes too. How can I update the page parameter inside the Carousel inside the button so that whenever I tap on the button carousel view will get the next page?

```
    GeometryReader { g in
                        Carousel(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, page: self.$page, height: g.frame(in: .global).height)
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
//                        self.isContinue.toggle()
                        if self.page+1 == Service.data.count {
                            self.page = 0
                        } else {
                            self.page += 1
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Devam Et")
```

Carousel

```
 struct Carousel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var width: CGFloat
    @Binding var page: Int
    var height: CGFloat
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Carousel.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let total = width * CGFloat(Service.data.count)
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.isPagingEnabled = true
        view.contentSize = CGSize(width: total, height: 1)
        view.bounces = true
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        let view1 = UIHostingController(rootView: ListPage(page: self.$page))
        view1.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: total, height: self.height)
        view1.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(view1.view)
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

ListPage

```
    struct ListPage: View {
    @Binding var page: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Service.data) { i in
                Card(page: self.$page, data: i, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
    class Service: ObservableObject {
    static let data: [OnboardingDetailElement] = [
        OnboardingDetailElement(image: "OnboardingImageOne", title: "Onboarding title 1", subtitle: "Onboarding detail 1"),
        OnboardingDetailElement(image: "OnboardingImageOne", title: "Onboarding title 2", subtitle: "Onboarding detail 2"),
        OnboardingDetailElement(image: "OnboardingImageOne", title: "Onboarding title 3", subtitle: "Onboarding detail 3"),
        OnboardingDetailElement(image: "OnboardingImageOne", title: "Onboarding title 4", subtitle: "Onboarding detail 4")
    
    ]
}
```

if you want to see the problem here is a 9-second video.
https://vimeo.com/498330545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this method inside the `Carousel` view.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
  uiView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: width * CGFloat(page), y: uiView.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
}
```